# select subquery cause mysql server to be unresponsive

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
DELETE FROM item_measurement
WHERE measurement_id IN (
   SELECT (-id) AS measurement_id
   FROM invoice_item
   WHERE invoice_id = 'A3722'
)
```

I've really tried hard to find what's wrong with the code. I tried to run this in a php page, which doesn't respond. I also tried the same line in phpmyadmin, infinite spinning circle and I had to restart the server(MAMP on Mac 10.9). No error was given in browser/

If I run the delete and select separately, they both finish very quickly. I don't think it's a performance issue because the separate run took < 0.1 sec each.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit:

I also found that a simple select statement will also suspend mysql:

```
select *
    from item_measurement
    where measurement_id in 
    (select -id from invoice_item where invoice_id='A3722')
```

Follow up:

The query will run successfully, just taking unexpectedly long to run. Here's the result:

~200k rows in item_measurement table

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below inline view produces temp table (stored in MySQL Internal area):

```
(
SELECT (-id) AS measurement_id
FROM invoice_item
WHERE invoice_id = 'A3722'
)
```

and measurement_id search in above temp table. but temp table has NO INDEX. so it's slow.

modify like this. this uses INDEX:

```
DELETE item_measurement
FROM item_measurement m, invoice_item i
WHERE m.measurement_id = (-i.id)
  AND i.invoice_id = 'A3722'
```

Edited

for same reason, below query also slow

```
select *
from item_measurement
where measurement_id in 
(select -id from invoice_item where invoice_id='A3722')
```

that's why MySQL manaul says use join rather than use sub-query.

Comment: Is there a big performance impact from the lack of index, if the temp table contains < 10 rows?

Comment: no. how many records in `select -id from invoice_item where invoice_id='A3722'` and item_measurement table has how many records.

I think item_measurement table is big.

Comment: item_measurement contains ~200k rows. How long do you think it'll take for a full scan?

Comment: I have no idea. it depends on you hardware. (but I guess it's not too slow)

if `select * from item_measurement i, invoice_item m where i.measurement_id = -m.id AND m.invoice_id='A3722')` is fast, DELETE statment that I suggested is fast

Comment: Thank you for your join method. Yes, it runs successfully for me. I'm still doubtful that the subquery is slower than it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just a question but what are you using an alias in your sub-query?  I am no expert though.

```
DELETE (What?)
FROM item_measurement
WHERE measurement_id IN
(SELECT -id FROM invoice_item
WHERE invoice_id = 'A3722')
```

Comment: I copied the subquery from elsewhere. However, removing the alias doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM `item_measurement` WHERE `measurement_id` in ( SELECT `id` as measurement_id FROM `invoice_item` WHERE `invoice_id` = 'A3722' )
```

Comment: Apart from removing the `(-)`, how is this any different to what the op has tried?